# Angular 2: How to attach unique div id in multiple tabs

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have several tabs with same page elements. One of the element contains a map div based on location details. I could get the map initialized for the first tab opened. The next tab when I open it throws up error as the div id containing the map is already initialized. How to make the div id unique (dynamic) for each map initialization in different tabs? Any idea would help me!

Comment: Can you share your component and html code?

Comment: Finally I solved it using ChangeDetectorRef.detectChange() method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to generate a completely unique id which you can then set with `[id]="getUniqueId()"`:

```
  getUniqueID(): string {

    let d = Date.now();

    if (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === 'function') {
      d += performance.now();
    }

    const id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {

      const r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;

      d = Math.floor(d/16);

      return (c === 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });

    return id;
  }
```